# How to import a json file format into CouchBase lite from Android App

Tags: android, json, xml, sqlite, couchbase-lite

I'm new with NoSQL concepts and I would like to understand which is the best way to load an JSON file format into an Android App (version 5).

As-is I receive an xml format and store the data received from a remote Server into my Android App, parsing the xml-data with KXml API, and save it into db with SQLite, but the task keeps some time when the file it's about 20 MB (parsing huge xml file with Kxml Api take some time :( ).

Surfing the net, I have found some interesting concepts about working with JSON file format, instead xml one's without parsing it, but saving into and NoSQL database like `CouchBase` lite.

So I would like to ask:

1. It is possible to load a JSON file format into  CouchBase lite database?
2. It is possible work with documents in my bulk avoiding duplication?
3. Which is the diff between Couchbase lite vs CouchBase mobile?

Thanks!

Comment: Bomberlatinos9 it is good form to accept an answer when your question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to load a JSON file format into CouchBase lite
>   database?

Yes . Couchbase Lite is a JSON document store. In your Android app. you would typically use a library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to parse and convert your JSON to a native object that you would then use within your app. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/UniversityLister-Android) app that discusses how you can use JSON with Jackson and Couchbase Lite

> Which is the diff between Couchbase lite vs CouchBase mobile?

Couchbase Mobile stack comprises of Couchbase Lite, which is embedded local database that runs on your mobile clients, the Sync Gateway that your clients talk to and which is responsible for data synchronization , data routing and authorization and the Couchbase Server which actually persists the data. The Clients running Couchbase Lite talk to the Sync Gateway, and the Sync Gateway talks to the Couchbase Server.